# How to insert the woocommerce permalink to a tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to insert the woocommerce permalink of product to a tag, could anyone please help me.
my code is:

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
    $product = "get_page_by_title( 'Product Title', OBJECT, 'product' )";
    echo '<a  href="<?php echo get_permalink( $product->ID ); ?>">View More</a>';
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
        global $product;
        $id = $product->get_id();
        echo '<a  href="' . get_permalink( $id ) . '">View More</a>';
    }
```

Or if your need is to get it by title, try:

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
        global $product;
        $title = $product->get_title();
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_title($title))) . '">View more</a>';
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Where do you call this function ?

Comment: Cheers friend :)